# Calculate employee count by hour and day

Tags: python, r, excel, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have employee id, their clock in, and clock out timings by day. I want to calculate employee count by hour by day. Excel formula would work too.

My sample data looks like this:

```
Employee ID   Day      Clockin      Clockout
1             Mon        7:00          15:00
1             Fri        7:00          15:00
2             Wed        8:00          22:00
2             Mon        10:00         18:00
2             Fri        9:00          20:00
3             Mon        7:00          8:00
```

My output should look like this:

```
Timestamp   Mon   Tue   Wed  Thu   Fri 
7:00        2      0     0    0     1
8:00        1      0     1    0     1
9:00        1      0     1    0     2
10:00       2      0     1    0     2
11:00       2      0     1    0     2
```

I tried to mutate `clock in` and `clock out` column but didn't work. I would prefer a solution in R. I tried solution mentioned here [Calculate the days per month between checkin and checkout dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210306/calculate-the-days-per-month-between-checkin-and-checkout-dates-in-r) but doesn't seem to work in my case

**Example of input**

```
ID  Day Clockin Clockout
Employee 1  Mon 7:00    15:00
Employee 2  Mon 8:00    15:00
Employee 3  Mon 12:00   14:00
Employee 4  Mon 13:00   20:00
Employee 5  Mon 15:00   22:00
Employee 6  Mon 23:00   23:30
```

**Example of output**

```
Mon Count 
7:00    1
8:00    2
9:00    2
10:00   2
11:00   2
12:00   3
13:00   4
14:00   3
15:00   2
16:00   2
17:00   2
18:00   2
19:00   2
20:00   1
21:00   1
22:00   0
23:00   1
```

If you pay attention to the count, you will find it changing when anyone clocks in or clocks out through out the day.

Comment: I have edited the question one more time. If you scroll to the bottom you will see UPDATE 2 where i have taken an example of input situation and output. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: `15:00` count for me is 4

Comment: I updated based on new data.  Some of the counts are not the same as in your expected.

Comment: at 14:00 employee number 3 clocked out so count will become 3 and at 15:00 employee 2 and employee 1 clocked out  so employee count will be 1 and at 15:00 employee 5 clocked in so count will be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated than it seems, since if an employee works the night shift until the next day, we need to change the day that we are counting their presence after midnight.

For that matter, I wrote my own function which takes the day, clock in, and clock out and returns a sequence of time (1 hour intervals) along with the day associated with each interval. See below;

```r
time.seq <- function(day.i, start.i, end.i, step.i = '1 hour'){
  
  require(lubridate)
  require(DescTools) ## to get the abbreviated weekdays

  start.i <- as.POSIXct(start.i, format="%H:%M")
  end.i <- as.POSIXct(end.i, format="%H:%M")
  
  if (start.i > end.i) { ## accounting for working on the next day (after midnight)
   end.i <- end.i + days(1) 
  }

  out.h <- seq(start.i, end.i , step.i)
  
  ## Going to the next day based on difference in time (unit = days)
  day.abb.ex <- c(day.abb, "Mon")
  
  out.d <- day.abb.ex[which(toupper(day.abb) == day.i) + 
            c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(diff(floor_date(out.h, unit = "day"))/86400)))]
  
  out <- list(DAY = out.d, HOUR = out.h)
  
  return(out)
}
```

Then using that function, and similar to the logic used in the other answer, we can get the count for each hour.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(HOUR = list(time.seq(Day, Clockin, Clockout)[["HOUR"]]),
         DAY = list(time.seq(Day, Clockin, Clockout)[["DAY"]])) %>% 
  unnest(c(HOUR, DAY)) %>% 
  count(Day=DAY, Hour = format(HOUR, '%H:%M'), name = "Count") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Day, values_from = Count) 

#> # A tibble: 22 x 8
#>    Hour    Fri   Mon   Sat   Sun   Thu   Tue   Wed
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 07:00     2    NA     1    NA     1     1     1
#>  2 08:00     2    NA     1    NA     1     1     1
#>  3 09:00     2    NA     1    NA     1     1     1
#>  4 10:00     4    NA     1    NA     3     3     3
#>  5 11:00     4    NA     1    NA     3     3     3
#>  6 12:00     5     1     1    NA     4     4     4
#>  7 13:00     5     1     1    NA     4     4     4
#>  8 14:00     5     1     1    NA     4     4     4
#>  9 15:00     5     1     1    NA     4     4     4
#> 10 16:00     3     1    NA    NA     3     3     3
#> # ... with 12 more rows
```

#### *Data*:

```r
df <- structure(list(Employee.ID = c(462L, 462L, 559L, 559L, 559L, 
559L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 560L, 715L, 715L, 715L, 715L, 715L, 
791L, 791L, 791L, 791L, 802L, 802L, 802L, 802L), Day = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
8L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("", "FRI", "MON", "SAT", 
"SUN", "THU", "TUE", "WED"), class = "factor"), Clockin = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "10:00", "12:00", 
"20:00", "7:00"), class = "factor"), Clockout = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("", "15:00", "17:30", 
"18:00", "18:15", "19:45", "20:00", "22:00", "4:00", "4:15", 
"4:45"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you would need `pivot_wider(names_from = Day, values_from = Count, values_fill = list(Count = 0))`  it should work fine

Comment: It works. thank you. I had to install DescTools in order to make it work. I also created a function to address the problem, however, my solution is a lot longer than yours. (I answered my own question, in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If we are using the hour with 'Clockin', in `R`, we can get the `count` of 'Day', 'Clockin' and reshape into 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   transmute(Day = factor(Day, levels = c("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT")),
         Clockin = ymd_hms(Clockin)) %>% 
   count(Day, Clockin) %>% 
   complete(Day, Clockin = seq(min(Clockin), max(Clockin), by = "1 hour"),
          fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
   mutate(Clockin = format(Clockin, "%H:%M")) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Day, values_from = n)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  Clockin   MON   TUE   WED   THU   FRI   SAT
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 07:00       0     0     0     0     1     1
#2 08:00       0     0     0     0     0     0
#3 09:00       0     0     0     0     0     0
#4 10:00       0     1     1     1     1     0
```

#### Update

With the new data

```
 df2 %>%
    transmute(Day,  Hour = map2(as.POSIXct(Clockin, format = '%H:%M'),
         as.POSIXct(Clockout, format = '%H:%M'), ~ seq(.x, .y, by = '1 hour'))) %>%
    unnest(c(Hour)) %>%
    count(Day, Hour = format(Hour, '%H:%M'))
# A tibble: 17 x 3
#   Day   Hour      n
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 Mon   07:00     1
# 2 Mon   08:00     2
# 3 Mon   09:00     2
# 4 Mon   10:00     2
# 5 Mon   11:00     2
# 6 Mon   12:00     3
# 7 Mon   13:00     4
# 8 Mon   14:00     4
# 9 Mon   15:00     4
#10 Mon   16:00     2
#11 Mon   17:00     2
#12 Mon   18:00     2
#13 Mon   19:00     2
#14 Mon   20:00     2
#15 Mon   21:00     1
#16 Mon   22:00     1
#17 Mon   23:00     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Employee ID` = c(462L, 462L, 559L, 559L, 559L, 
559L), Day = c("FRI", "SAT", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI"), Clockin = c("1899-12-31 07:00:00", 
"1899-12-31 07:00:00", "1899-12-31 10:00:00", "1899-12-31 10:00:00", 
"1899-12-31 10:00:00", "1899-12-31 10:00:00"), Clockout = c("1899-12-31 15:00:00", 
"1899-12-31 15:00:00", "1899-12-31 18:00:00", "1899-12-31 18:00:00", 
"1899-12-31 18:15:00", "1899-12-31 18:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")




df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("Employee 1", "Employee 2", "Employee 3", 
"Employee 4", "Employee 5", "Employee 6"), Day = c("Mon", "Mon", 
"Mon", "Mon", "Mon", "Mon"), Clockin = c("7:00", "8:00", "12:00", 
"13:00", "15:00", "23:00"), Clockout = c("15:00", "15:00", "14:00", 
"20:00", "22:00", "23:30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: It throws an error: object 'Day' not found, (day is a column name already)

Comment: I apologies for going over and over the problem statement. Output I am expecting is slightly different from what I am getting suing the above code. I have added more details in my question above (if you scroll to the bottom).  If someone clocked in at 7:00 am and next clock on the day is at 10:00 am then total count should display 1 for 7:00 , 8:00, 9:00 and at 10:00 am count will be 2. It will remain 2 until another person clocks in on the same day.

Comment: are you subtracting clock outs from the total count ? because at 20:00, count is 2; at 21:00 no activity so count remains 2, at 22:00, employee 5 clocked out, so count will 1, at 23:00 employee 6 clocked in so count will become 2.

Comment: @Belle I was trying to understand your previous comment. In my code, it is looping over each row of 'Clockiin', 'ClockOut', get the sequence of hour from the corresponiding Clockin to 'ClokOut by 1 hour, unnest it and then did the count

Comment: @belle When you say `employee 5 clocked out`, are you removing the '22:00' from it?

Comment: yes. when employee 5 clocked out, i will remove him from the count.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of sharing my solution here in case if it helps someone. Only difference this solution has is , I have added an additional column `positions`as a filter. You can remove that filter if your problem is similar to mine as stated above. Otherwise, this filter helps with sorting `hours` by `position id`.

```
  #loading libraries
    library(lubridate)
    library(readxl)
    library(stringr)
    library(tidyr)
    #read data
    df <- read_excel('data_sample.xlsx',
                     col_types = c('numeric', 'text', 'date', 'guess', 'guess','skip', 'numeric'))
    #convert clocks to float for faster comparisons
    df$`Clock In` = hour(df$`Clock In`) + minute(df$`Clock In`) / 60
    df$`Clock Out` = hour(df$`Clock Out`) + minute(df$`Clock Out`) / 60
    #remove shallow records
    df <- df[!(df$`Clock In` == df$`Clock Out`),]
    #24 hours strings
    hours = lapply(0 : 23, function(i) str_pad(paste(toString(i), ':00', sep=""), 5, pad = '0'))
    #empty presence matrix
    hours_mat = c()
    #fill the presence matrix with ines when exists in work place
    for (r in 1:nrow(df)) {
      lis = c()
      for (i in 0:23) {
        if (i < df[r, 'Clock In'] | i >= df[r, 'Clock Out']){
          lis[i + 1] <- 0
        }
        else {
          lis[i + 1] <- 1
        }
      }
      hours_mat <- rbind(hours_mat, lis)
    }
    #convert  matrix to dataframe
    hours_df = as.data.frame(hours_mat)
    colnames(hours_df) <- hours
    #bind the matrix to the original dataframe
    final_df <- cbind(df, hours_df)
    #aggregate presence count over date in every position
    result <- aggregate(final_df[1:nrow(final_df),7:ncol(final_df)],
                        by=list(Date = final_df$Date, Position = final_df$Position),
                        FUN=sum)
    #factorize dates for converting from wide to long format
    result$Date = factor(result$Date)
    #wide to long format
    long_result <- gather(result, Timestamp, Count, '00:00':'23:00',
                          factor_key = TRUE)
    #long to wide format using dates
    result_wide <- spread(long_result, Date, Count)
    #to select a particular position, uncomment this line :
    #result_wide <- result_wide[result_wide$Position == 'your required position as number']
    #write the final output to "output.csv"
    write.csv(result_wide, 'output.csv')
```

and sample data is as follows -

```
structure(list(`Employee Number` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Day = c("THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN", 
"WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN", "WED", "THU", "THU", "FRI", 
"SAT", "SUN", "WED", "THU", "THU"), Date = structure(c(1577923200, 
1578009600, 1578096000, 1578182400, 1578441600, 1578528000, 1578614400, 
1578700800, 1578787200, 1579046400, 1579132800, 1579132800, 1579219200, 
1579305600, 1579392000, 1579651200, 1579737600, 1579737600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ClockIn = structure(c(-2209021200, 
-2209021200, -2209021200, -2209021200, -2209021200, -2209023000, 
-2209021200, -2209021200, -2209021200, -2209021200, -2209075200, 
-2209021200, -2209021200, -2209021200, -2209021200, -2209021200, 
-2209075200, -2209021200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    `Clock Out` = structure(c(-2208992400, -2208992400, -2208992400, 
    -2208992400, -2208992400, -2208994200, -2208992400, -2208992400, 
    -2208992400, -2208992400, -2209075200, -2208999600, -2208992400, 
    -2208992400, -2208992400, -2208992400, -2209075200, -2208999600
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Department = c(20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20), Position = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
    35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35)), row.names = c(NA, -18L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```